# Why is EOF not sticky in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, posix, glibc

There's a old bug about `fgetc`/`fread` not being C99 compliant in `glibc`.  The short version is that EOF was supposed to be sticky, but it was not. This was fixed in 2.28.

Some snippets from https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1190:

```
commit 2cc7bad0ae0a412e75270be5ed41d45c03e7a931
Author: Zack Weinberg <zackw@panix.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 21 19:12:51 2018 -0500

    [BZ 1190] Make EOF sticky in stdio.
    
    C99 specifies that the EOF condition on a file is "sticky": once EOF
    has been encountered, all subsequent reads should continue to return
    EOF until the file is closed or something clears the "end-of-file
    indicator" (e.g. fseek, clearerr).  This is arguably a change from
    C89, where the wording was ambiguous; the BSDs always had sticky EOF,
    but the System V lineage would attempt to read from the underlying fd
    again.  GNU libc has followed System V for as long as we've been
    using libio, but nowadays C99 conformance and BSD compatibility are
    more important than System V compatibility.
```

And from the release notes of 2.28:

> All stdio functions now treat end-of-file as a sticky condition.  If you
> read from a file until EOF, and then the file is enlarged by another
> process, you must call clearerr or another function with the same effect
> (e.g. fseek, rewind) before you can read the additional data.  This
> corrects a longstanding C99 conformance bug.  It is most likely to affect
> programs that use stdio to read interactive input from a terminal.
> (Bug #1190.)

The change in behavior is definitely visible in Python 2 going from <2.28 to >=2.28.

However, in Python 3, EOF does not appear to be sticky even in glibc >= 2.28.

```bash
$ cat read.py
with open('read.txt', 'rb') as fobj:
    while True:
        b = fobj.read(1)
        if b:
            print(b)

$ ldd --version | grep GNU
ldd (GNU libc) 2.28

$ python --version
Python 3.8.13

$ touch read.txt

$ python read.py &
[2] 37538


$ echo 1 >> read.txt
b'1'
b'\n'

$ echo 1 >> read.txt
b'1'
b'\n'
```

In Python 2, you don't get any printing after the echo.

I found https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22578299 where someone stated that:

> In Python 3, file I/O is is implemented using POSIX read(), write() etc., rather than C stdio.

The implication being that POSIX read() does not have sticky EOF. Is this discrepancy expected? Desirable?

I want a sticky EOF!

Comment: well python is open source ...

Comment: Why do you want sticky EOF? It's often useful to repeatedly poll if more data has been read from the file

Comment: You couldn't implement `tail -f` without this feature.  If you want sticky EOF, then close the file after you hit EOF.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Sticky EOF wouldn't stop you from implementing `tail -f`. With sticky EOF, you could still just clear the EOF indicator after hitting EOF.

Comment: Assuming you had a way to clear the EOF.  Does Python?  I'm not aware of one, so Python does it for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts: `fobj.seek(0, 1)` should do it (or at least, it would if Python was going through the fseek/fread functions that actually interact with that indicator, instead of seek/read - I don't know if POSIX seek affects the EOF indicator).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the devs didn't think particularly hard about this corner case. One user [reported](https://bugs.python.org/issue1523853) sticky EOF as a documentation/behavior discrepancy in Python 2 (the docs didn't say anything about sticky EOF), which lead to [the addition of a note](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) in the Python 2 docs.

Comment: Then [another user](https://bugs.python.org/issue1706039) submitted a patch that tried to turn off sticky EOF in Python 2, but without any justification for considering it a bug besides the existence of the prior bug report. The patch didn't work right, and work stalled until the issue was eventually closed due to Python 2 reaching end of support.

Comment: Note that there is no particular reason why Python's file reading functionality should have the same corner case behavior as C's file reading functionality, and Python and C already have many differences in their file handling.

Comment: Since Python doesn't even need to be implemented with C, there is no reason that Python must adhere to C99 for its own file handling.